# Total length count instead of only preceding token length in Regex

Tags: regex

I have the regex as below:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9,.'-]+\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9,.'-]{3}
```

eg: 'a bcd': here the above regex count apply for bcd but i want the {3} to validate whole from a to d as 5.

When i hover to {3} it says Quantifier. Match 3 of the preceding token but i want it to count all
a bcd

My regex is perfect for me, can anybody modify just to count all word without other affect on my regex.

Comment: regex101.com might be helpful for you.  Otherwise, please can you provide examples that your pattern should match and also examples where your pattern should NOT match?

Comment: Do you mean like this `^[a-zA-Z0-9,.'-]\s[a-zA-Z0-9,.'-]{3}$` https://regex101.com/r/2vq950/1 or perhaps like this `^(?=.{5}$)[a-zA-Z0-9,.' -]+$` https://regex101.com/r/DQohUe/1

Answer (score 1):

Total length count is enforced with lookahead:

```py
^(?=.{X}$)([a-zA-Z0-9,.'-]+\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9,.'-]{3}
```

Remove `{3}` if not necessary.

Replace `X` with the string length limit.

Add `$` at the end of end of string after the last pattern is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Regex can't do that, you have to use a programming language to validate this. You could do it in 2 steps:

1. Your RegEx
2. Some kind of `length`, `size` or `strlen` (depending of your language).

Your string is valid *iff* it passes both tests.

Edit:

if you insist on using RegEx, you can replace step 2 by another regex that looks like `.{1,5}` (any characters from 1 to 5 times). But you still have to do it in 2 steps.